# Последовательная загрузка списка классов (ООП)

Tags: javascript

Предположим в массиве содержатся названия классов

```
var arr = ['class1','class2','class3' и т.д.];
```

Мне нужно эти классы загрузить последовательно вместе с конструкторами и т.д. Классы определены ранее по коду.

сейчас делаю так

```
for(let key in arr){
    let obj = new arr[key];
    // здесь дальнейшая работа с объектом
}
```

но вылетает ошибка, т.к. arr содержит названия классов, а не сами классы.

как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Если это не `Node.js`:

```
for(let key in arr){
    var myClass = window[arr[key]];
    let obj = new myClass;
    // здесь дальнейшая работа с объектом
}
```

Comment: а если node.js??? тогда??

Comment: @Ивашка, Попробуйте `global` вместо `window`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким не обычным образом можно получить класс/функцию(функцию конструктор бывает называют классом). Работает для любого глобального объекта.

```js
class class1 { 
  // я class
}

function class2 () {
  // я function
}

const arr = ['class1', 'class2']

for(let str of arr) {
  let myClass = (new Function(`return ${str};`))()
  console.log(myClass)
}
```

Обычную функцию можно получить через window, но class нет, только если записать вручную:

```
window.Foo = class Foo { ... }
```

Подробнее о классах, не являющихся свойствами оконного объекта в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321636/es6-classes-what-about-instrospection/30322216#30322216), в котором цитируется спецификация [ECMA2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-global-environment-records), [раздел 8.1.1.4: Глобальные записи окружающей среды](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-global-environment-records):

> A global Environment Record is logically a single record but it is specified as a composite encapsulating an object Environment Record and a declarative Environment Record. The object Environment Record has as its base object the global object of the associated Realm. This global object is the value returned by the global Environment Record’s GetThisBinding concrete method. *(E.g., the global object referenced by `window` on browsers — T.J.)* **The object Environment Record component of a global Environment Record contains the bindings for all built-in globals (clause 18) and all bindings introduced by a *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, or *VariableStatement* contained in global code. The bindings for all other ECMAScript declarations in global code are contained in the declarative Environment Record component of the global Environment Record.**

То есть нововведения (let, const, и class declarations) не доступны в глобальном объекте, это видно по этому коду:

```js
let a = 1
const b = 2
class c {}

console.log(window.a, window.b, window.c)
```